Расширение/Параметр VSCode/IntellijIDEA которое показывает возвращаемый тип
Существует ли расширение или параметр для vscode или intellijidea, который показывает возвращаемый тип функции?
Я это увидел в видеоролике про редактор кода ZED, хотелось бы такой же функционал в VSCode или IntellijIDEA Community 

Тег языка программирования поставьте, плиз.

@HolyBlackCat а зачем он здесь ? Я же не про код спрашиваю, а про функционал программного обеспечения

@HolyBlackCat java, c++

Для каждого языка свой плагин, иногда их несколько разных на выбор. Какие-то умеют показывать типы, какие-то нет. У каждого свои разные настройки, где-то надо эти типы включать, и т.п.

Нажмите на кнопку [edit] и поставьте туда эти теги, плиз.

@HolyBlackCat Добавил

Спс. Про джаву не знаю, но для плюсОв плагин Clangd (который заменяет стандартный С/С++-плагин от мелкомягких) показывает типы по дефолту. (Можно спрятать под хоткей через "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed",.)

Это можно сделать в VSCode, вам нужно включить inlayHints.
Вы можете использовать мои настройки и исправить их под себя. (Эти настройки не захватывают обычные JS/JSX файлы)
"[typescript][typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "onUnlessPressed"
},
"typescript.inlayHints.enumMemberValues.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.functionLikeReturnTypes.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.parameterTypes.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "all",
"typescript.inlayHints.propertyDeclarationTypes.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": true,

